# Find Segments lying inside another using Geography points SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sqlgeography

Let me explain the attached picture [Yellow line termed as Construction Planning identified by Planning Id and all other colors termed as Construction Segment identified by SegmentId](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZ8UQ.png). I am trying to use `STDistance` function of Geography Points to find the `SegmentId=12689` and `SegmentId=12687` by passing the `PlanningID=25801`. My program should return the values `12689` and `12687` since these two wholly lie within the `PlanningID=25801`. However it should exclude the value `SegmentId=12688` since that segment doesn't lie fully or most part of the segment is not inside the Construction Planning.
I have created the following script in SQL server

```
declare    @Planningid INT
declare    @agencyID int
set @Planningid=25801
set @agencyID=79
DECLARE @finalresult int
DECLARE @result TABLE (id INT, starting sys.geography, ending sys.geography,
                          chachedroute sys.geography)
DECLARE @tablevar TABLE(id INT)
insert into @result select id,
starting,Ending,CachedRoute from Route R where AgencyId=@agencyID and LayerId=1 
                  and CachedRoute.STDistance((select CachedRoute from route 
                                               where id=@Planningid))<0.5
select * from @result
/* the above part of the code is working fine as it should */

/* the next part of the logic is not working and it is excluding all the Segment Id when it 
                                should not and should only exclude SegmentId=12688 */
insert into @tablevar
select id from @result where 
            chachedroute.STDistance((select starting from route where id=@Planningid))<700 
            and 
            chachedroute.STDistance((select ending from route where id=@Planningid))<700
intersect
select id from @result

select * from @tablevar
```

I guess the problem is because of the `and` logic in the second part of the code where it calculates if the values are within 700 meters. This code was first created with the concept that each `PlanningId` should have only one `SegmentID` which is why I coded it by matching both the starting and ending of the segments. But now the modification is that a single `PlanningId` can have multiple `SegmentID` where I guess lies the problem.
Any help how to modify the code will be really appreciated.
The table `Route` contains the following attributes:

1. ID (int)
2. Starting (Geography Points)
3. Ending (Geography Point)
4. Cached Route (Geography Point)
5. LayerId (int)
6. AgencyId(int)

The value `LayerId=1` refers to `Construction Segment` and `LayerId=4` refers to `Construction Planning`

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the above Function as the following to make it work:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetSegmentId]
(   
    @Planningid INT,
    @agencyID int
)

RETURNS @tablevar TABLE 
(
    id INT
)

AS

BEGIN
        declare    @CachedRoute geography
        DECLARE @finalresult int
        DECLARE @result TABLE (id INT, starting sys.geography, ending sys.geography,chachedroute sys.geography)
        

        set @CachedRoute = (select CachedRoute from route where id = @Planningid)

        insert into @result select id,
        starting,Ending,CachedRoute from Route R where AgencyId=@agencyID and LayerId=1 and CachedRoute.STDistance(@CachedRoute)<0.5 

        insert into @tablevar
        select id from @result where @CachedRoute.STDistance(starting)<700 and @CachedRoute.STDistance(ending)<700
        intersect
        select id from @result


    RETURN;
END;
```